# Why is the variable a is changed in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

```py
class PowTwo:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of powers of two"""

    def __init__(self, max=0):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
a = PowTwo(3)
b = iter(a)
print(next(a))
```

Without this snippet `b = iter(a)`, the output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mark/test2.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(next(a))
  File "/Users/Mark/test2.py", line 13, in __next__
    if self.n <= self.max:
AttributeError: 'PowTwo' object has no attribute 'n'
```

My question:

`b = iter(a)` I did not use `a = iter(a)`. How come variable a is changed here?

Comment: `__iter__` returns `self`. I'm not sure what's tripping you up. Please clarify.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, what I did not understand was that I applied the iter() function on variable a and assigned it to variable b.  However, variable a also acquired this self.n attribute in this process. I expected it to stay the same.

Comment: You can assign the same object to many names. It's still the same object.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Therefore, the iter(a) just added the self.n attribute to the object and object ID stayed the same?

Comment: Yes. I'll add an answer momentarily

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Your question is clear and contains all relevant information. The example is even fairly minimal. Being a beginner should not be punished, especially when you follow the rules.

Comment: thanks! I did not understand how object worked. Now I understand. I checked the id of a and b and they are the same.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, could you please give me an upvote on this question. I am banned from asking questions :(  This question needs one upvote to become a 0 score...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python objects can be assigned to multiple names. All those names will refer to the same actual object. For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
```

Both `a` and `b` refer to the same object. Setting `b[0] = 0` will also affect `a`, because it is the same object. This causes much grief to beginners.

To bind an object to a name, you assign it. Assignments have many forms. For example, `def` and `class` assign function and class objects to names, respectively. These names are not special, and you can re-bind them at will:

```
def a():
    print('Hi')

b = a   # b now refers to a function object
a = 1   # a is now an integer, while b is the original function
```

Another type of assignment happens when you pass arguments to a function. The objects you pass in are bound to the local names in the argument list. The function-local names refer to the exact same objects that you passed in, not copies:

```
a = 1
def f(x):
    print(x is a)
f(a)  # True
```

Return values work similarly, but in reverse. The object in the function is assigned to a name in the outer scope.

Now let's say you have an object `a = PowTwo(3)`. When you call `b = iter(a)` on it, the following things happen:

1. The call to `iter` is equivalent to `PowTwo.__iter__(a)`
2. The object you assigned to `a` in the global scope is bound to the argument `self` in `__iter__`
3. The object `self` in `__iter__` is bound to `b` by the return call

Now `a` and `b` refer to the same object. Calling `next(a)` or `next(b)` after that will pass the same object to `next`, since both names are bound to it.

If you had assigned `a = iter(a)`, you would be re-binding `a` to itself. While technically not a no-op, it would be equivalent to just calling `iter(a)` and discarding the redundant return value.

Answer (score 6):

Your `__iter__` is mutative: it sets the object's `n` attribute to `0`. This is the *only* initialization of `n` in your code. If `__iter__` is not called, `__next__` will not find `n` when it looks for it.

Mutative `__iter__` methods are a bad idea. You should perform initialization in `__init__`.

Comment: This is the second question I've seen today that does this. I wonder if it's some crappy popular tutorial everyone is following

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer also cleared some of doubts as well!  However, the system only lets me choose one. :(